# Cache music from BackgroundAudioPlayer in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-audio

Im using the background audio player to play music from the remote server.
Is there any way to save music files from Background Audio Player to local storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to create a streaming audio player and capture and save the parts of the track/file while playing it.